# Storage Transfer Service Jobs in GCP using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I need to create storage transfer service jobs in GCP using terraform code. I am to create the jobs however I need to use custom job names for the STS jobs. I do see an option to do so in console where it says *Autogenerate a unique, permanent job name upon creation*
If I uncheck the checkbox next to it, it asks me to enter an unique job name.
However I need to deploy multiple STS jobs using my terraform code at once instead of manually creating jobs one by one using console.
Can someone please help me with the configuration I need to add for the same?